# Improve Apache2 performance on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Windows Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu for Windows) for LAMP development. But Apache2 seems to be **very slow** as page refreshes take up to 10 seconds. Is there any to speed up Apache2 on Ubuntu for Windows?

I'm running a Symfony 2 Application with PHP 7.0.15 and MySQL 5.5.54. On a comparable native Ubuntu the refresh times are consistently below 1 sec.

Apache2 modules:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Comment: What's the application? Plain HTML? What's the environment, which resources are available to apache? Are you getting > 10 seconds on the same host apache is running on? Did you benchmark against the apache install on ubuntu you've mentioned in another ask? This is not enough information.

Comment: Updated the question with additional information

Comment: What does system load say, which process is the busiest when loading the site? When loading the site in your browser, what is the time to first byte? Let's narrow it down to apache, php or mysql causing the issue.

Comment: First byte received is after about 2 sec. Asset files that are parsed by the framework take about 3 sec queueing and 1 sec waiting for response. This is behavior on page with no SQL queries. To validate this a shut down MySQL and got the same results. CPU load is at 100% on a page refresh for the period of time the refresh needs ...

Comment: Same happens for a static page without any php calls?

Comment: Thanks for the continued help! A single HTML static page loads very fast, about 12ms. But a simple PHP page (e.g. phpinfo()) has about the same speed.

Comment: Well then, sounds like  you've narrowed it down to the database. Any chance to get performance  metrics from mysql?